# Override generated insert statement in JdbcIO with Apache Beam

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

I wanted to write records in Postgres with a column type set as json. In Python version of JdbcIO, WriteToJdbc has a "statement" parameter which is suppose to override the generated insert statement. It seems that it is not working at all

```
| 'Write to jdbc' >> WriteToJdbc(
                table_name="teacher",
                driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
                jdbc_url='jdbc:{}://{}:{}/{}'.format("postgresql", "your ip address", "5432", "postgres"),
                username="postgres",
                password="password"
                statement = 'insert into researcher(id, first_name, last_name, total, payload) values (?, ?, ?, ?, cast(? as json))'
            )
```

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: what sort of errors are you getting?

Comment: @Pablo It just ignores the "statement" parameter value and invokes the default insertion

Comment: if that's the case, then it sounds like a bug. Would you be willing to add details to this bug? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-10750

Comment: sure ! it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The Python version of JdbcIO is still experimental and not fully supported.  There's an open Beam JIRA ticket for this feature: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-10750