# Apache Beam pipeline with Write to jdbc

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to create a pipeline which is reading some data from Pubsub and writing to into a postgres database.

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
Device = NamedTuple(
     "Device",
     [
         ("id", str),
         ("userId", str),
         ("patientId", str)
     ])
coders.registry.register_coder(Device, coders.RowCoder)
p = beam.Pipeline(options = pipeline_options)

(p
   | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(topic="projects/us-vpc/topics/pipeline").with_output_types(bytes)
   | "Decode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
   | beam.Map(lambda x:
             Device(id= "e4f63782-66f5-4f49-911f-0b00efa5b23e", userId="Random",
                             patientId=str('12345')))
     .with_output_types(Device)
   | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(1))
   | 'Write to jdbc' >> WriteToJdbc(
       table_name= "patient_device",
       driver_class_name = db_driver_name,
       jdbc_url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name,
       username = dev-user,
       password = db-password
       )
) 
result = p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

I can see four steps are being created on the data flow after it is deployed on gcp.

1. ReadFromPubSub
2. Decode
3. Map
4. WindowInto

But the issue is 'Write to jdbc' step is not created on the dataflow.

**Here is the command to execute the dataflow:**

```
python pipeline.py --runner DataflowRunner --project us-con-project-location --temp_location gs://staging/temp --staging_location gs://staging/temp --region us-east1 --input_topic "projects/us-vpc/topics/pipeline" --subnetwork regions/us-east1/subnetworks/-public-01
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Examples Followed:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.24.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html

[Apache Beam pipeline with JdbcIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66761775/apache-beam-pipeline-with-jdbcio)

Answer (score 1):

Note that cross-language pipelines on Dataflow require [Runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/multi-language-sdks-for-building-cloud-pipelines). I'm not sure that JdbcIO works well for streaming though; you could try debugging this with a batch pipeline first (replacing your PubSub read with a simple Create).

Comment: I can see the events on pubsub after every publish so that is not an issue, the step  'Write to jdbc' itself is missing in the data flow.

Comment: Are you passing `--experiments=use_runner_v2`?

Comment: You are awesome, step created.

Comment: Note that as of the latest release, you no longer need to set this manually: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12590